# Mapping DataTables migration 1.9 to 1.10

Tags: javascript, json, datatables, migration

Hello StackOverflow community,
I'm looking for some help to migrate from Datatables 1.9 to 1.10. The notation is not the same anymore, so in order to keep the "old" code working with the new Datatables version, I need to map them. I wrote a json object "mapping", like that (it's just an extract), based on this link https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert :

```
var mapping : {"oLanguage" :  {"sEmptyTable" : "language.emptyTable"}};
```

Now, I would like to create a JSON object from "language.emptyTable" to :

```
{"language" : {"emptyTable"}}
```

I tried some different recursive functions but... call stack and so on.

I know it's not a very clean method to upgrade to new version but I have at least a hundred Datatables in my app and can't modify all this code in time, I will do it step by step and not in a hurry.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on it since yesterday and found the answer just after I posted this message... So, if someone is interested by the answer, here it is:

```
<script>
var txt = 'language.search';
var fn = function(str) {
    var obj = {};
    var pos = str.indexOf('.');
    //console.log(pos);
    if(pos != '-1') {
        //console.log(str.substr(pos+1));
        obj[str.substr(0,pos)] = fn(str.substr(pos+1));
    }
    else if (str.length) {
        obj[str] = {};
        //return obj;
    }
    return obj;
};

console.log(fn(txt));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert options, jQuery DataTables 1.10 has backward support of options used by jQuery Datatables 1.9.

See [Converting parameter names for 1.10](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert):

> The change is **fully backwards compatible** and you can continue to use the old versions of the parameter names and API methods as you were before.

Comment: Yes I know, but it's not true for all options, only the basics (I checked in the code). And I need a mapping for Tabletools (new "buttons") too...